# R: plotting mean and median of 2000 different random chi squared simulations

Tags: r, histogram, repeat

I am trying to run 2000 simulations of a randomized chi squared distribution, with n = 300 and df = 3. From each simulation, I want to take the sample mean and median, then ultimately plot the means and medians as histograms.

I've tried using the repeat loop function, with the histograms appearing after meeting the "if" condition.

```
n = 300
df = 3
randomchisq = rchisq(n = n,df = df)
i = 1
reps = 2000
xvals = "Chi squared sims"
twokchisqmean <- i:reps
twokchisqmed <- i:reps

repeat {
  twokchisqmean[i] = mean(randomchisq);
  twokchisqmed[i] = median(randomchisq);
  i = i+1;

  if (i==reps) {
    par(mfrow=c(1,2))
    hist(twokchisqmean, 
         main="Histogram of mean for 2000 chi squared sims",
         xlab = xvals)

    hist(twokchisqmed,
         main = "Histogram of median for 2000 chi squared sims",
         xlab = xvals)

  }
}
```

The plots seem not to appear in R Studio when I implement this code. No warnings appear in the console, either.

Comment: won't this just run an infinite loop because there is no `break` in the `repeat` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `repeat` statement will loop until it reaches a break, and only then will it return from the loop. Since you have no `break` in your `repeat` statement, your code will just run infinitely. Make sure you put a break in when you want it to stop:

```r
n = 300
df = 3
randomchisq = rchisq(n = n,df = df)
i = 1
reps = 2000
xvals = "Chi squared sims"
twokchisqmean <- i:reps
twokchisqmed <- i:reps

repeat {
  twokchisqmean[i] = mean(randomchisq);
  twokchisqmed[i] = median(randomchisq);
  i = i+1;

  if (i==reps) {
    par(mfrow=c(1,2))
    hist(twokchisqmean, 
         main="Histogram of mean for 2000 chi squared sims",
         xlab = xvals)

    hist(twokchisqmed,
         main = "Histogram of median for 2000 chi squared sims",
         xlab = xvals)
    break #Break once the plot is added
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, though it seems the plots still aren't appearing after I include the break.

Comment: I have updated the code to include all variables, running this in a clean R environment produces the plots just fine, maybe try running this new code? If this still doesnt work let me know

Comment: It seems the issue was my environment. Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries! Glad i was able to help :)